# How can I unstage multiple hunks using magit?

Tags: emacs, magit

I have discovered the joys of magit and lately found a need to split out some hunks so I can have a commit I can use later for merging in which I don't want all the hunks.

I know I can TAB to see hunks, and then 'u' to upstage the hunk from the commit but when doing this using tramp to a remote server can be slow.

What I would like to do, is mark the desired hunks and then use an unstage action on all the marked hunks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible but I am making some changes which will eventually allow this.

Edit: On the next branch that now is possible.

Comment: Sounds great :) How does one do it? (Is it the ediff staging feature you're referring to? I've just noticed that now. Very nice. It's a one-file-at-a-time feature by the looks of it, yes?)

Comment: The same way that multiple files are staged. Set the mark on one end, move to the other, press `s`.

Comment: Ah, so it's a way to un/stage multiple *contiguous* hunks, rather than an arbitrary selection?

Comment: Yes, I won't add a staging area for the staging area.

Comment: :) Do you think it's feasible to enhance `magit-ediff-stage` to work across multiple files? (Such that you can work through the full set of changes -- perhaps as a sequence of ediff invocations; one per file -- and then do a single 'stage' action at the end?) A little like `git add --edit` in some ways, I guess.